# NDSolve gives different solutions for different intervals

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, complex

I try to solve the ODE for the complex function `w[t]`, which looks like

```
phases = {-0.300522 + 0.953775 I, -0.896597 - 0.442848 I, 
 0.436416 + 0.899745 I, 0.182403 + 0.983224 I, 0.99707 + 0.0764909 I};

initial = 0.121282 + 0.553207 I;

RHS[phases_, t_]:= Module[{M, RHSFlow}, M = Length[phases]; 
 RHSFlow = -1/2*1/M*(1 - Abs[w[t]]^2)*
   Total[(phases - w[t])/(1 - Conjugate[w[t]]*phases)]];

sol = NDSolve[{D[w[t],t]== RHS[phases,t],w[0]==initial}, w, {t,0,T}]

W = w/.sol[[1]]
```

With surprise, I have noticed that the behavior of the solution depends on `T`. It is clearly visible from the attached plot:

[image]

Comment: Length[initial] is zero what makes RHS[initial, t] infinite.

Comment: With a guess to change the ODE to `D[w[t],t] == RHS[phases, t]`, the jump up occurs over the same time interval for all values of `T` (V13.1).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have fixed this typo. I use V12.0 & will revise my code

Comment: As I said, I don't get the problem in my version, but one thing that varies with the integration interval is the maximum allowable step size (specifically controlled by `MaxStepFraction`). I suggest setting `MaxStepSize` to something smaller than `30`, say `MaxStepSize -> 5` or `10`. For me the transition to $|w|=1$ occurs over $20\le t\le 30$. You may have to decrease `MaxStepSize` until the transition stabilizes.  The maximum step taken before the transition with the default settings on my system is $\Delta t=$ `1.017`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial data and parameters (`initial` and `phases`) are given with low precision while equation is nonlinear. To solve this problem we can, for example, rationalize  `initial` and `phases` as follows

```
phases = Rationalize[{-0.300522 + 0.953775 I, -0.896597 - 0.442848 I, 
    0.436416 + 0.899745 I, 0.182403 + 0.983224 I, 
    0.99707 + 0.0764909 I}, 10^-30];

initial = Rationalize[0.121282 + 0.553207 I, 10^-300];

RHS[phases_, t_] := Module[{M, RHSFlow}, M = Length[phases];
   RHSFlow = -1/2*1/M*(1 - Abs[w[t]]^2)*
     Total[(phases - w[t])/(1 - Conjugate[w[t]]*phases)]];

sol[T_] := 
 Module[{T0 = T, s}, 
  s = NDSolveValue[{D[w[t], t] == RHS[phases, t], w[0] == initial}, 
    w, {t, 0, T0}]; s]
```

Visualization

```
{Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[sol[T][t], {T, {300, 400, 500, 1000}}] // Abs], {t, 0, 200}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Table[sol[T][t] - sol[300][t], {T, {400, 500, 1000}}] // Abs], {t, 
   0, 200}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {400, 500, 1000}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Yes, indeed the problem is low precision